# Is it dangerous not to connect ground to a 12 V power supply?

Tags: power-supply, ground, 12v

I have a 12 V regulated power supply that I use for a car audio amplifier in my home and I only have it hooked up with a cord that has a line and a neutral, no ground. Could this be dangerous or cause any other issues? It's been working fine so far and I don't get a shock when I touch the case of the power supply.

[image: apologies for poor image quality]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the 12V supply double-insulated? (Does it have the double-insulated symbol, a square box inside another one, on its label?) Double insulation is the standard way to ensure safety without a ground.

Comment: Helpful: [Why don't we use neutral wire for to ground devices and earth wire for closing the circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211010/why-dont-we-use-neutral-wire-for-to-ground-devices-and-earth-wire-for-closing-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Can you post pictures of the power supply and cable you're talking about?

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply, they provide an earth connection so it requires connecting to earth.

The safety earth is there to protect you, and also the equipment, in the event of a fault that connects a dangerous voltage to the chassis and metalwork.

The fact that no such fault has happened so far does not stop it happening in the future. On the day it happens, if at all, you'll need the safety earth. The consequences of not having it range from pain to serious harm to death.

Take no pointless or easily-avoidable chances. Use a proper mains cable with earth and change the risk from unlikely or improbable to nigh-on impossible.

It's a good lifelong habit to adopt and will cost you all of about £2 for a cable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, will definitely invest in a proper cable!

Answer (score 2):

Some appliances may give a shock if there's a wiring fault.   Some, will only give a shock if there's TWO wiring faults.   Each may be
safe if there are no faults.

But, local safety standards (which differ according to century and
region) may require... almost ANYTHING.

If you might touch the 12V output wiring of the power supply, and if there
is any hazardous AC voltage involved, a ground-fault interrupter
(GFI, or GFCI) and the two-prong plug should make the system
shock-safe.   Any modern three-prong power plug has a ground
that would also make the system shock-safe (if the design passes
modern safety
standards that I'm familiar with).

There is no absolute safety, so there's no possible complete
answer to this question.   Notably, even if there's NO AC power
involved, batteries have been known to catch fire.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast! I'll get a grounded cable to avoid any risks